# How to test JMS request without creating SOAP or REST project in SOAPUI

Tags: soap, soapui, tibco-ems, tibco-business-works

I am trying to automate some testing for TIBCO BW project (version 5.7 cannot migrate to newer) I found that SOAPUI can be used for testing JMS. However, it requires that I create a REST or SOAP project and supply it with wsdl. I don't want to test SOAP  over JMS but plain JMS communications. Is there any way to do it in SOAPUI? If not, can you recommend any other tool that can be used for unit testing automation of TIBCO Business Works project? I cannot afford BWUnit. I did a lot of research and can't find any other tutorials or solutions. All solutions are about testing SOAP over JMS

Comment: Have you tried the documentation? https://www.soapui.org/jms/getting-started.html

Comment: of course I did and it didn't help so I am trying to get help here

Answer (score 1):

For your use case, you can give a try to [JMSToolBox](https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox) and its "script" feature, combined with the "templates" and "variables" features

(FYI, I'm the author of [JMSToolBox](https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox))

Comment: does it support tibco ems 5.0? What is the license for your code? is it open-source? I would give you + but i don't have reputation sorry man

Comment: Did you check the links in my answer? JMSToolbox is an open source project with source held in github (the link i posted...) and as stated there, it's license is GPL v3. The TIBCO plugin has been developped and tested with v8.3. It may work with TIBCO v5 . The vest way to answer this is to install JTB and test it with your server. https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox/wiki

Answer (score 1):

I will restrict my answer to SOAP UI as that is the original question.

The only way I have found in SoapUI to perform pure JMS testing, is to use a "Groovy Script" as a Test Step in a Test Case - basically, one must define a JMS session/connection information in HermesJMS and use that session in a "Groovy Script" to publish/browse/receive JMS messages.

Below, I will describe the steps to setup a JMS Session in HermesJMS to TIBCO EMS and also the steps to setup a simple SoapUI project (non-SOAP, non-REST) to use a Groovy Script step in a Test Case, to publish messages to an EMS queue and browse messages from the same queue. This concept can then be extended to achieve various complex test scenarios, assertions for verification of data, load tests for performance testing etc.

> Disclaimer: I have only tested this concept for a simple use-case in SoapUI free version, so I am not sure what are the limitations of using a groovy script; One obvious limitation which comes to mind is the fact that one will need to write actual code to perform all the tests, instead of using a no-code approach provided by SoapUI, but there may be other limitations as well.

So, here are the steps:

**1. Setup and Install**: When installing SoapUI ensure to select "install Hermes JMS". I am using SoapUI 5.5.0 free version and I chose to install HermesJMS as part of the default SoapUI installation, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: SoapUI installation with HermesJMS]

**2. Launch HermesJMS**: Start SoapUI and Launch HermesJMS from within SoapUI.
     
    Select Project > Start HermesJMS. On the screen which will pop-up (shown below), click OK. This will launch HermesJMS.

[image: Start HermesJMS]

**3. Create a new session**. Click on "Create Session" button as shown below.
[image: Click Session Button]

**4. Enter a name for the session**: Use session name as tibemslocal. click Apply and then OK. Session is now available in the sessions panel and ready to be configured.

[image: Set session name]

[image: Session in hermes manager]

**5. Add a provider**: Click the Providers tab at the bottom. Right-click in the classpath groups area and select "Add Group".

[image: Add group]

**Assign a group name**: Assign the name as TIBCOEMS-8.4 and click OK.

[image: Set group name]

**Add JAR files**: Right click on library and select "Add JAR" and then select the JARs to be added and click Open, as shown in second screenshot below. A new window will pop-up, which will require you to choose whether to scan the jars or not, as shown in screenshot 3 below -- select Scan. This will scan the jars and add them to the library. Now, add all the Jars as shown in the fourth screenshot below and click Apply. This will add the provider. Click OK and restart HermesJMS for the configuration to take effect.

[image: Add Jars - Step 1]

[image: Add Jars - Step 2]

[image: Add Jars - Step 3]

[image: Add Jars - Step 4]

**6. Setup Connection Factory**: After HermesJMS has been restarted, from the sessions menu, select tibemslocal, right-click and select edit. In the connection factory section, select TIBCOEMS-8.4 as the loader (provider which we created in the previous step) and select class as "com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnectionFactory", as shown in screenshot below. click Apply.

### [image: Connection Factory Setup]

**7. Connection Factory Property Setup**: Now, in the same session editor window, setup properties for Connection Factory, as shown in the screenshot below. Click Apply.

[image]

**8. Plug-in Property Setup**: Now, in the same session editor window, select Plug In value as "TIBCO EMS" instead of "Default" and setup properties for Plug in, as shown in the screenshot below. Click Apply and OK.

[image]

**9. Verify Session**: TIBCO EMS Server used in the setup above must be running. To verify correctness of the JMS session setup, right-click on the "tibemslocal" session and click on Discover, as shown in the first screenshot below. If the setup is correct, it should discover the queues and topics, as shown in the second screenshot below. Close HermesJMS.

[image: Click on discover]

[image: Destinations discovered]

**10. Setup SoapUI Project**:

- *Create Empty Project*: Click on Empty Project button on the left and rename the project to JMSTester, as shown in the screenshot below.

  [image: New Empty Project]
- *Add New Test Suite*: Add a new TestSuite and call it SimpleJMSTests.

  [image]
- *Add A New Test Case*: Add a new test case and call it "SendToAndBrowseQueue".

  [image]
- *Add A New Test Step*: Add a new Test Step as "Groovy Script" and add the following code to it. Ensure the TIBCO EMS instance has a queue named "test" created on it.

  ```
  import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.jms.JMSConnectionHolder
  import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.jms.util.HermesUtils
  import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.jms.JMSEndpoint
  import hermes.Hermes
  import javax.jms.*

  def date1 = new Date()
  def milli = date1.getTime()

  log.info "Start Groovy Script Execution: " + date1
  log.info "Unique Partial CorrelationID (cid) value for this session is: " + milli

  def jmsEndpoint = new JMSEndpoint("jms://tibemslocal::queue_test::queue_test");
  def hermes = HermesUtils.getHermes(context.testCase.testSuite.project, jmsEndpoint.sessionName)
  def jmsConnectionHolder = new JMSConnectionHolder(jmsEndpoint, hermes, false, null, null, null);
  Session queueSession = jmsConnectionHolder.getSession();
  Queue queueSend = jmsConnectionHolder.getQueue(jmsConnectionHolder.getJmsEndpoint().getSend());
  Queue queueBrowse = jmsConnectionHolder.getQueue(jmsConnectionHolder.getJmsEndpoint().getReceive());

  MessageProducer messageProducer = queueSession.createProducer(queueSend);
  TextMessage textMessageSend = queueSession.createTextMessage();
  textMessageSend.setText("1 - jms message from groovy");
  textMessageSend.setStringProperty("cid", "Msg:1:" + milli);
  messageProducer.send(textMessageSend);
  textMessageSend.setText("2 - another jms message from groovy");
  textMessageSend.setStringProperty("cid", "Msg:2:" + milli);
  messageProducer.send(textMessageSend);

  QueueBrowser qb = queueSession.createBrowser(queueBrowse);
  Enumeration en = qb.getEnumeration();

  if (en.hasMoreElements()) {
   log.info "There are messages to process from the queue."
  }
  while (en.hasMoreElements()) 
  {
   Message msg = en.nextElement();
   TextMessage tm = (TextMessage) msg;
   def cid = tm.getStringProperty("cid");
   if (cid != null) {
    if (cid.contains(milli.toString())) {
     log.info "Message From This Session --> " + tm.getText()
     log.info "cid = " + cid
    } else {
     log.debug "Message Not from This session --> " + tm.getText()
     log.debug "cid = " + cid
    }
   } else
    log.info "CorrelationGUID is null"
  }//ENDS - while
  jmsConnectionHolder.closeAll() // don't forget to close session and connection
  log.info "done"
  ```
- Execute Groovy Step: Execute the groovy step and it should produce the following output, as shown in the screenshot below.

  [image: Groovy Script output]

In these steps, we configured HermesJMS with TIBCO EMS and then used the HermesJMS session to create a connection to TIBCO EMS using Groovy script from SoapUI and invoked the Groovy Script as a test step to publish two messages to a EMS queue and browsed the same messages. This confirms the capability to publish/browse messages.

I believe this functionality can be extended to receive messages from queues/topics, test content/property values with assertion etc., which is left for the reader/OP to implement and test.

Hope this will be helpful. If there are any questions please let me know.

## References

- Groovy Script Sample: The aforementioned groovy script has been copied from the SoapUI tutorial and modified for the need of this demonstration. Original Source is available here - [SoapUI Sample Groovy code](https://www.soapui.org/jms/working-with-jms-messages.html)
- SoapUI and HermesJMS: See this article on SoapUI website - [SoapUI and HermesJMS Setup](https://www.soapui.org/jms/getting-started.html)